# Historically, did Calculus' concepts depend upon Geometry in their development?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

I know particular mathematical topics did not arise in a vacuum, but around a host of other related ideas.

Here my functions are differentiable functions from and to euclidean spaces.

I know the "analytic" definition of the derivative of a function; the limit of an algebraic expression. For this we don't need to know about curves or geometry, so in principle we don't need to know anything about geometry to do calculus.

So I am wondering did the creators of calculus (Newton and Leibniz), and early users, always have in mind the "analytic geometry"? (if anyone has read their works). Did they think geometrically with slopes of tangent-lines as they came up with the idea of the derivative, and used it?

Comment: Newton was a brilliant geometer.  He proved to himself, using calculus, that by his law of universal gravitation, planets follow elliptical orbits.  But, he realized that none of his colleagues would understand this work, and proved it again using only classical geometry.  It was this second set of proofs that he published, setting up the conflicts that would follow.  

Leibniz already had the fundamental theorem of calculus relating the slopes of tangents to the areas under curves. And $\frac {dy}{dx}$ is his short-hand for slope.

Comment: Geometry was very much involved in it, well before Newton. As far back as (& including) Galileo , new geometric results were being made  by the new method of "indivisibles" : essentially integration. Attempts at justifying it were usually vague or illogical, sometimes to the point of being laughable.......Archimedes' essay on his methods, which included integration, was not re-discovered until the 19th century.

Comment: @DougM So it seems from what you're saying that Leibniz's fundamental theorem of calculus was to him a geometric theorem involving curves, lines (tangents), and areas? Is this accurate?